# Kubernetes VIP configuration for HA

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, keepalived

We are trying to setup kubernetes HA with haproxy and keepalived.
We are setting up the cluster with 3 masters and 6 workers.
The above said binaries are installed on all the three masters. keepalived is enabled and the virtual ip is attached to one of the haproxy acting as ACTIVE load balancer. In case of haproy failure the vip would fail over to the one of the other two haproxy. the virtual is getting routable in the masters and the fail over is working as expected.

The issue is that the virtual ip is not routable in  the workers as the keepalived is configured only on masters. My question is how do we make the virtual ip routable in the workers so the worker can connect the masters via VIP?

note that ip address of  masters, workers and virtual ip are all from same subnet.